# Spring losing session authentication with TestRestTemplate

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, spring-security, integration-testing

I am running a test using Spring's TestRestTemplate to execute 2 api calls in sequence. 
My Test has this infrastucture:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
```

Api call 1:

- `GET`
- `HttpSecurity` allows this request always
- `@PreAuthorize("isAnonymous()")`
- Automatically logs in the user using these:

:

```
final Authentication myCustomAuthentication = ...MyCustomObjectForNewLogin)
eventPublisher.publishEvent(new AuthenticationSuccessEvent(myCustomAuthentication));
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(myCustomAuthentication);
((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes()).getRequest().getSession(true).setAttribute("SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT", SecurityContextHolder.getContext());
```

Api call 2:
 - `POST`
 - `@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('MyAuthorityThatHeAlwaysHasWhenLoggedIn')")`

The issue is:
On the second call I always get a 401 Unauthorized. I have traced this down to the following:
in the spring class `AnonymousAuthenticationFilter#doFilter:96`
This is happening:

```
if (SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(
                    createAuthentication((HttpServletRequest) req));

            if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
                logger.debug("Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: '"
                        + SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() + "'");
            }
        }
```

for some reason it looks like the context lost the authentication and is hence being repopulated as an anonymous user. I read that this value is a ThreadLocal in some cases which is why i am also setting the attribute in the session so it can be re-loaded however it seems to not be reloaded. How can i either force it to be reloaded or inject the value into that holder. (Note this series of api calls works when done through postman. Only fails in the test).

I am executing the calls as follows:

```
@Autowired
private TestRestTemplate rest;

rest.getForEntity(UriComponentsBuilder.fromPath("/api1/").queryParam("myparm", "val").build(true).toUri(), String.class));
rest.postForEntity("/api2/", new HttpEntity<>(myExpectedObject, state), String.class)
```

Comment: Having a similar issue, any progress here?

Comment: I recall it had something to do with some handling of the csrf token i was doing in between the calls. (I had a header) But i doubt it is related to your problem

Comment: thanks, in my case I wasn't closing the connection properly after each request and this somehow resulted in authentication issues